# State management for a React app using Providers

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and i am working on a legacy project.

The project don't use any specific state management library. It handles state using Contexts and Reducers as in the example below:

```
const reducer = // ...

const NotificationContext = createContext(initialState)

const NotificationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  const v = useMemo(() => ({ state, dispatch }), [state])

  useEffect(() => {
    Logger.log('NotificationContext init')
  }, [])

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={v}>
      {children}

      {state.notif && <Notification key={state.notif.id} id={state.notif.id} message={state.notif.message} />}
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  )
}

NotificationProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}

export { NotificationContext, NotificationProvider }
```

At the end, we wrap our application with all the providers in a pyramidal structure:

```
    <PlayerProvider>
      <ProgramProvider>
        <ChannelProvider>
          <SubscriptionProvider>
            <DebuggerProvider>
              <NpvrProvider>
                <SidebarProvider>
                  <KeyboardProvider>
                    <CacheProvider>
                      <Suspense fallback={<span />}>
                        <Switch>
                          <Route exact path="/" component={SplashscreenContainer} />
                          <Route path="/" component={MainProtectedContainer} />
                        </Switch>
                      </Suspense>
                    </CacheProvider>
                  </KeyboardProvider>
                </SidebarProvider>
              </NpvrProvider>
            </DebuggerProvider>
          </SubscriptionProvider>
        </ChannelProvider>
      </ProgramProvider>
    </PlayerProvider>
```

We have big performance issues in our application. I was wondering if this way of handling state was the cause of it, or if it's an acceptable way of state management.

Comment: looks fine to me, what kind of performance issues? may be worth using react devtools to trace which components are re-rendering and why, if you suspect the problems are related to unnecessary renders